# Function can not be found when cloning model which uses lambda layer with user defined function in Keras

Tags: keras

I want to adapt gumbel-softmax in my model. I found tensorflow implemenation by the author. I brought it to my source code and use it in lambda layer replacing existing softmax acativation layer. it worked, but the problem happened when this model clone other model, it got error. Any solution or experience to work around this?

Thanks for reading.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dev/workspace/starcraftrlchallenge/python/saida_agent_example/zealotVsZealot/zealot_vs_zealot_v0_Proposed_discreted_gumbel_mb.py", line 269, in <module>
    agent.compile([Adam(lr=5e-5), Adam(lr=5e-5)], metrics=['mae'])
  File "D:\dev\workspace\starcraftrlchallenge\python\core\algorithm\MAProposed.py", line 321, in compile
    self.actor_train_on_batch = self.actor_optimizer()
  File "D:\dev\workspace\starcraftrlchallenge\python\core\algorithm\MAProposed.py", line 163, in actor_optimizer
    self.target_actor = keras.models.clone_model(self.actor)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 251, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 139, in _clone_functional_model
    layer(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 687, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "D:\dev\workspace\starcraftrlchallenge\python\saida_agent_example\zealotVsZealot\model\ac_networks_gumbel_mb.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    action_logit = Lambda(lambda h : gumbel_softmax(h, hard=True))(h)
NameError: name 'gumbel_softmax' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at `clone_model` [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6612da89516247503f03ef76e974b51a434fb52e/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py#L131) it seems it uses the same `from_config` method used in model loading. There (when loading model) special care is taken of custom objects. As mentioned in [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/):

> If the model you want to load includes custom layers or other custom classes or functions, you can pass them to the loading mechanism via the custom_objects argument.

While there is no such argument for `clone_model`. A simple workaround would be to save and load the model in order to clone it:

```
from keras.models import load_model

def gumbel_softmax:
    ....

model.save('tmp.h5')
clone = load_model('tmp.h5', custom_objects={'gumbel_softmax': gumbel_softmax})
os.remove('tmp.h5')
```